# How to write a script in ksh to exit from the terminal?

Tags: linux, ksh

I am writing a shell script. I used `case` statement regarding certain stuff. I have an option/case as `q` that should exit from the terminal.

```
 case "$i" in
         1) some script. ;;
         q) break && exit;;
```

but it's only exiting from the script, not the terminal.

Can anyone help me regarding that? Note the shell is `ksh`.

Comment: What is the application that runs the terminal? In many cases it would just be a matter of telling that application to close the window when your script ends.

Comment: I am using putty. And yes, i agree we can do the setting in application too. but as of now my requirement is to do through script only.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bad approach

```
q) kill ksh
```

#### Good approach

In your main shell, do this

```
alias yourscript='exec yourscript'
```

so the script takes over the shell and quits the shell upon ending.

Comment: hello, thanku fo the reply.i tried both ways, but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

`ksh` supports `$PPID`. This variable identifies the process number of the parent of the `ksh` shell.

So if your script is run from *any* shell (and it is interpreted by `ksh` because of its shebang) then this should make this shell exit:

```
kill -s SIGHUP $PPID
```

Note it will also kill the script, unless the script was invoked with `nohup` or some similar trick was used.

Then your terminal emulator should exit automatically, if not configured otherwise (e.g. PuTTY has "Close window on exit" option that can be set to "Never").